# Qt Creator не запускает проект

Tags: qt, qtcreator, mingw

Переустановил Visual Studio, QtCreator. 
В VS всё починил, а в QtCreator запускаю проект и ничего не происходит.

В Tools->Options->Kits на каждом компиляторе стоит жёлтый треугольник с восклицательным знаком, кроме MinGW, который я устанавливал для VS. Но если проект запустить вместе с MinGW, то ничего опять не происходит.

2 раза переустанавливал Qt с QtCreater'ом, выбирал все инструменты доступные, но всё бестолку.

Comment: В закладку Проекты зайдите и посмотрите что там у вас происходит

Comment: MinGW для Visual Studio? Оригинально!

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Вы имеете в виду, какую вкладку "Проекты"? На начальном экране или в Параметрах?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если вы считаете, что вы таким ответом помогаете мне, то хочу вас разочаровать!

Comment: Да, эту вкладку. Там посмотрите внимательно на настройки. Выберите с мингв и попробуйте запустить проект

Comment: @AlexanderChernin к сожалению мне не удалось подходящего пункта, который мне пофиксил проблему. Есть Manage Kits, в котором лежат компиляторы MSVC и MinGW, но не знаю, что с ними делать

Comment: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qtcreator/1.3.0/creator-project-pane.html